# How to avoid/minimize the indent of a list within a list?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-lists

I have an unordered list(ul) within another. The indent is huge and I would like to have no indent of the sublist.

```
<ul>
    <li id="menu_home"><a href="./"><b>Home</b></a></li>
    <li id="menu_about"><a href="./?p=about"><b>About</b></a></li>
    <li id="menu_products">
        <a href="./?p=products">
            <b>Products</b>
        </a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="./?p=products#infiniSpam">infiniSpam</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="./?p=products#infiniNet">infiniNet</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d8d7P/1/

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this CSS:

```
ul ul {
    padding:0;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/d8d7P/2/)**